# Is there a way, using built-in Excel functions only, to check one set of data against another?

Tags: excel

More specifically, assume there is a full list of names and addresses on a worksheet. There is also a second worksheet with a subset of the names from the full sheet, with newly updated addresses.

Is there a way to loop through all of the names on the full sheet, check if it matches any of the names in the revised sheet, and, if so, update the relevant address on the full sheet with the relevant new address from the second sheet?

I managed to get it to successfully check the names from sheet1 against the names on sheet2, but I don't know of a way to tell the formula what cells to get the address information from in the event of a match.

The format of the cells is firstname, lastname, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode for both worksheets.

Comment: research Vlookup: Vlookup(NameOnSheet1,RangeOnSheet2,ColumnToReturnIfMatch,true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP is the function you are looking for.  Once you have mastered this, you might want to look into the INDEX AND MATCH functions, which can achieve the same result more efficiently and (sometimes).

For complete description of VLOOKUP, see [Microsoft's support page for VLOOKUP](http://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?f4c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

It's very helpful to have a unique id code for each individual. If you have one, include it in column A of both datasets.  If you don't have one, you can construct an ID field, but you'll need to do some manual work to make sure it is unique.  (Suggestion on how to go about constructing ID code at end of answer.)

Put the ID in column A.  Columns B-H will have your other fields, so address1 will be in column D.

You're going to want an absolute reference for your original data. Let's call the worksheet with old data Worksheet1 and the one with the new data Worksheet2.  Then the reference for original data (including ID code) will be **Worksheet1!$A:$H**

VLOOKUP will match the ID code in new worksheet with the one in the old, and then pull data from the column you specify. To look up the matching address1 for the first person in the new dataset, you'd use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Worksheet1!$A:$H,4,0)
```

where

- "A1" is the id code that you want to match to.
- "Worksheet1!$A:$H" is the original data
- "4" tells excel to look in the 4th column ("D") in the original data
- "0" tells excel to only return an error if there is not an exact
  match.  (This is important.)

Do this once for each column that you want to compare (address2 will look the same as address1, but will reference column 5 instead of column 4).  Havind done this, you can copy to the rest of the rows in your new worksheet.

Procedure above will pull old data into appropriate row of new worksheet. If you just want to know if there is a change to a particular field, you could do something like:

```
=IF(D1=VLOOKUP(A1,Worksheet1!$A:$H,4,0),"","changed")
```

There are obviously lots of ways to refine this and condense the information.